# Eslint Jsdoc Plugin is not exectued

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc

I am trying to run the [ESLint JSDoc plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc)

When I run `npx eslint .` airbnb rules are enforced but not the jsdoc ones requiring to add JSDoc.
Am I missing something ?

Here is a [test repo](https://github.com/QuentinDela/eslint-test)

```
package.json

{
  "name": "eslint-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^18.4.3"
  }
}
```

```
index.js

const fn = (a) => {
  console.log('a :', a);
  return a;
};

module.exports = { fn };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the ESLint configuration file. Add `.eslintrc.js` to the root of your project. Then copy the following basic configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    plugins: ['jsdoc', 'import'],
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:jsdoc/recommended',
        'plugin:import/errors',
        'plugin:import/warnings',
         'airbnb-base'
    ]
}
```

See [Configuring ESLinf](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) for more informaion.